# Python Dash Plotly Express - trendline mean

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to put mean as a trendline in the scatter plot

```
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022',
                                   '02/01/2022','02/01/2022','02/01/2022','02/01/2022',
                                   '03/01/2022','03/01/2022','03/01/2022','03/01/2022'],
            'value': [12,15,5,9,22,27,12,16,6,2,18,16,17,19]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    


fig = px.scatter(df, x="date", y="value", trendline="ols") 
fig.show()
```

but looking at the documentation https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/, there is no trendline mean,
any suggestion on how to do it?

[image]

EDIT:
so I think this is the closest it gets; the issue is because the scatter and the line plots are separated in the color list.

```
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022',
                                   '02/01/2022','02/01/2022','02/01/2022','02/01/2022',
                                   '03/01/2022','03/01/2022','03/01/2022','03/01/2022'],
            'value': [12,15,5,9,22,27,12,16,6,2,18,16,17,19],
                  'color' : ['yes','yes','yes','no','no','maybe',
                            'yes','no','no','yes',
                            'no','maybe','maybe','yes']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    


fig = px.scatter(df, x="date", y="value", color='color')
for i in df['color'].unique():
    yy = df[df['color'] == i]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name = i, mode='lines', x=df['date'].unique(), y=yy.groupby('date')['value'].mean().tolist()))

fig.show()
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxL4n.png): [image]

EDIT 2:
How to match colors:

```
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly#[:3]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022','01/01/2022',
                                   '02/01/2022','02/01/2022','02/01/2022','02/01/2022',
                                   '03/01/2022','03/01/2022','03/01/2022','03/01/2022'],
            'value': [12,15,5,9,22,27,12,16,6,2,18,16,17,19],
                  'color' : ['yes','yes','yes','no','no','maybe',
                            'yes','no','no','yes',
                            'no','maybe','maybe','yes']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

fig = px.scatter(df, x="date", y="value", color='color')
for i,c in zip(df['color'].unique(), colors):
    yy = df[df['color'] == i]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=i+' Mean', mode='lines', x=yy['date'].unique(), y=yy.groupby('date')['value'].mean().tolist(), line_color=c))
    
    

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Try trendline="lowess", from that link you mentioned.  That may be what you want.

Comment: I did a lot of research and there are no averages in the trendlines currently offered. So I think the only way is to simply get an average and add a line chart. `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=df['date'].unique(), y=df.groupby('date')['value'].mean().tolist(), line_color='red'))`

Comment: @r-beginners thank you for the code, I was thinking about it too but didn't put it in the code, I edited my question with the color added.

Comment: @r-beginners any idea how to match colors, please? so scatter and line plot have the same color for each 'color'.

Comment: I think we should use the PLOTLY default color set of 3 from the beginning and add them to the loop process. `colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[:3];for i,c in zip(df['color'].unique(), colors):
    yy = df[df['color'] == i];
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=i, mode='lines', x=df['date'].unique(), y=yy.groupby('date')['value'].mean().tolist(), line_color=c))`

Comment: @r-beginners thank you! added it in my question, with 2 changes, no need to use [:3], and the axis x should use the filtered yy['date'].unique(), in case someone finds this useful!